# How to remove items from one ListBox which already exists in other ListBox items

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make matches between two `ListBox`es and remove them from second `ListBox`?

For example, I have `foo` in `listbox1`, if it is also in `listbox2` then remove foo from `listbox1`.

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward. Loop over the items in listbox2 and remove them from listbox1. What exactly are you getting stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple:

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    listBox2.Items.Remove(item);
```

I hope to be helpful:)

Comment: You've got the listboxes backwards according to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
  foreach(var item in listBox1.Items)
  {
      // check if listbox2 contains the current item in the foreach loop.
      // don't forget to use: using System.Linq;
      bool hasItem = listBox2.Items.Contains(item);


       // if it has it than remove it
       if(hasItem)
          listBox2.Items.Remove(item);
   }
```